# Unable to pass a variable through to a vue file

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm using laravel 10 and vue 3 and vite and what I'm trying to do is pass a variable from the laravel blade file through to my vue file.

The problem I'm having is that the vue file isn't picking up the variable and I'm not sure as to why or if I did something wrong.

Here is my laravel blade file

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('title', 'Manage Users')

@section('content')
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div id="user-edit">
            <user-edit :user="{{ json_encode($user) }}"></user-edit>
        </div>
    </div>

    @vite('resources/js/admin/users/users.js')
@endsection
```

here is my vue file

```
<template>
    <div style="width: 100%;"  class="p-5">
        {{ user.name }}
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: ['user'],
    components: {},
    data() {
        return {

        }
    },
    watch: {

    },
    computed: {

    },
    methods: {

    },
    beforeMount() {

    },
    mounted() {
        console.log('mounted', this.user);
    }
}
</script>
```

this is my users.js

```
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import VueCookies from 'vue-cookies';

import i18n from '../../../lang/index';

import Index from './Index.vue';
import UserEdit from './UserEdit.vue';

const app = createApp(Index);
const app2 = createApp(UserEdit);

app.use(VueCookies);
app.use(i18n);
app.config.devtools = true
app.mount('#user-app');

app2.mount('#user-edit');
app2.use(VueCookies);
app2.use(i18n);
app2.config.devtools = true
```

and in my app.js

```
import "./bootstrap"
import "~public/vendor/jquery/jquery";
import "~public/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle";
import "overlayscrollbars";
import "~vend/almasaeed2010/adminlte/dist/js/adminlte";
```

and this is my vite.config file

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import legacy from '@vitejs/plugin-legacy'
import path from 'path';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        vue(),
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/css/main.css',
                'resources/sass/app.scss',
                'resources/js/app.js',
                'resources/js/admin/users/users.js'
            ],
            refresh: true,
        }),
        legacy({
            targets: ['defaults', 'not IE 11'],
        }),
    ],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '~nodem': path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
            '~vend': path.resolve(__dirname, 'vendor'),
            '~public': path.resolve(__dirname, 'public')
        }
    },
    build: {
        chunkSizeWarningLimit: 2000, //1 MB
    },
});
```

I've tried different ways of my users.js file to call my vue file.
For example I tried this

```
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import UserEdit from './UserEdit.vue';

const app = createApp({});
app.component('user-edit', UserEdit);
app.mount('#user-edit', () => {
 console.log('Vue app mounted!');
});
window.Vue = app;
export default app;
```

UPDATE:

This is the code I'm trying to do

laravel blade

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('title', 'Manage Users')

@section('content')
    <app>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div id="user-edit">
                <user-edit :user="{{ json_encode($user) }}"></user-edit>
            </div>
        </div>
    </app>

    @vite('resources/js/admin/users/users.js')
@endsection
```

App.vue

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <slot></slot>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: [],
    components: {},
    data() {
        return {

        }
    },
    watch: {

    },
    computed: {

    },
    methods: {

    },
    beforeMount() {

    },
    mounted() {
        console.log('mounted app');
    }
}
</script>
```

app.js

```
import "./bootstrap"
import "~public/vendor/jquery/jquery";
import "~public/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle";
import "overlayscrollbars";
import "~vend/almasaeed2010/adminlte/dist/js/adminlte";


import {createApp} from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
const app = createApp(App);

import users from "../js/admin/users/users.js";
app.use(users);
```

users.js

```
import UserEdit from "./UserEdit.vue";
export default {
    install: (app) => {
        app.component('user-edit', UserEdit);
    }
}
```

UserEdit.vue

```
<template>
    <div style="width: 100%;"  class="p-5">
        User Edit
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: ['user'],
    components: {},
    data() {
        return {

        }
    },
    watch: {

    },
    computed: {

    },
    methods: {

    },
    beforeMount() {

    },
    mounted() {
        console.log('mounted', this.user);
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, i don't think that passing your component to the createApp function will work, your component needs to be inside your app,

so the html should look like :

```
<app>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div id="user-edit">
            <user-edit :user="{{ json_encode($user) }}"></user-edit>
        </div>
    </div>
</app>
```

And you should have an App.vue :

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <slot></slot>
    </div>
</template>
```

and pass the app component to the createApp function :

```
const app = createApp(App);
```

root components can't have props.

Also for your users.js i would do :

```
import UserEdit from './UserEdit.vue';
export default {
    install: (app) => {
        app.component('user-edit', UserEdit);
    }
}
```

and then do that in app.js :

```
import users from './users.js'


app.use(users);
```

If you want to have another file for admin like admin.js, it's fine, but i would not create a file for every page.

if you want your build to be divided into smaller files, you can use the chunk feature instead

And also you could use dynamic imports :

```
import { defineAsyncComponent } from 'vue'
export default {
    install: (app) => {
        app.component('user-edit', defineAsyncComponent(() => import('./UserEdit.vue')));
    }
}
```

It will put your component on a separate js file and automatically load it when needed

UPDATE :

You don't even need an App component, using {} works :

```
import './bootstrap';

import {createApp} from "vue";
const app = createApp({});

import users from "./users";
app.use(users);


app.mount('#app')
```

```php
<body>
<div id="app">
    @yield('content')
</div>
</body>
```

```php
@section('content')
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div id="user-edit">
            <user-edit :user="{{ json_encode($user) }}"></user-edit>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

Comment: would `const app = createApp(App);` go in my users.js file?

Comment: No, you should have only one createApp for your entire application

Comment: I'm not sure if I misunderstood something, but it doesn't seem to be working. I've updated my question to have what I did under the UPDATE section

Comment: Do you see the user when you inspect the source ? it should work i have exactly the same setup, i have a :data attribute inside blade and i can access it using this.data inside the components

Comment: Also i think you can remove the @vite inside blade, since you import users.js from app.js and app.js is the entry point of vite

Comment: I see it when I inspect the source, but I don't see the vue file in my browser and I also don't see the vue dev tools

Comment: Do you see your component running in the browser ? when you inspect do you still see `<user-edit :user="{user here}"></user-edit>` ? or you see the actual component code ? (`<div style="width: 100%;"  class="p-5">`...)

Comment: Also be sure to alias vue : `resolve { alias: { vue: 'vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js' } }` inside defineConfig in your vite.config.js so runtime compilation works

Comment: Here is a working example  of the code i pasted in my answer : https://github.com/lk77/example-app

Comment: THANK YOU SOOOO MUCH. The example you made on github helped so much.